# Phenomenon in ForgeViewer 7.68

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

We are using ForgeViewer.
I tried using ForgeViewer 7.68, which was recently released to the public,
and experienced the following phenomenon.

1. When loading a file with a large number of parts with memory limit The loading process stops at the viewer loading screen and does not finish.
   The memory Limited are configuration as follows.

   loaderExtensions: {svf: "Autodesk.MemoryLimited",},
   memory: {
   limit: 256,
   },

   We checked with nwd files with 100,000 members.
   Then it continues to load as shown in the image below,
   No matter how long I wait, the model does not appear.
   [loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB2DR.jpg)
   Previous versions would have displayed the model correctly.
   Do you have a solution?
2. When selecting parts with memory limit applied, some of the parts that are not selected disappear.
   Grant memory limits in the same way as the above item.
   If you select a component in this state, some of the unselected components will be hidden.
   This happens on both PC and iOS.
   [before select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSjht.png)　　　[after select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDClf.png)
   We have confirmed that this happens with any 3D files
   This phenomenon will not be fixed until you select a location without a component.
   This phenomenon was present in the previous version, but was the same in the latest version.
3. With ifc files, they are displayed at an unintended angle after loading.
   When the ifc file is loaded, it is no longer displayed in the correct orientation as shown in the image below
   [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLuyj.png)　　　　　[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssY1r.png)
   If the screen is moved even slightly in this state, it will suddenly change to the normal orientation.
   Also, as it is now, the upper right cube and the model are not oriented in the same way, so it is in a strange state.
   Do you know the cause of this?

Comment: Is it the same with the latest viewer version 7.7 as well?

Comment: @varunpatil  Not yet confirmed with version 7.7.
Has there been an update to 7.69 and 7.7 that would resolve these issues?
I looked at the changelog and it didn't seem to matter.

Comment: We will try to reproduce the issues #1 and #2 locally. #2 doesn't seem to be a new issue, as you said that it also happened with older versions. It would be helpful to know how you translate the designs, i.e. if they are using SVF or SVF2. MemoryLimited will only work with SVF.
For the IFC issue (3), it would be great to clarify the open questions, and maybe get a test file to reproduce the issue.
Is it possible to give the test file? email to forge.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Hi, this was late, i had missed sharing your file, is it resolved now?